# Java: Iterating over multidimensional arrays Concept

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am try learn Java  since last 3 yrs, still i found i am very weak in Core java.

I have the following doubt from the below code, please help me.

- why `nums[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);` , `(i+1)*(j+1)` is used with `+1`.
- why first `array[]` is used to intialize the for-each loop i.e in line `for(int x[]:nums)..`

Code:

```
//Use for-each style for on a 2-dimensional array
//Code source:From online site
public void foreachmultiarrya()
{

    int nums[][]=new int [3] [5];
    //give nums some values
              for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
            nums[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);
    int sum=0;
    for(int x[]:nums)
    {
        for(int y:x)
        {
            System.out.println("Value of y:"+y);
            sum+=y;
        }
    }
        System.out.println("Sum="+sum);   
}
```

Comment: If my question is not clear then please comment here , i will try to explain you

Comment: Where is this code snippet from? Is it a tutorial or something that you're trying to understand? Or is it code written by you that doesn't work like you expected?

Comment: Well, first of all you should always write code following style conventions. If not, it is much harder to read and understand by others, thus making it less likely that someone will be willing to help you.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan From a book by Herbert Schildz

Comment: @broncoAbierto thank you for suggestion, what does it mean `following style conventions`?

Comment: Danny, general coding conventions are general guidelines for formatting code source, naming methods, objects and so on. They are very well documented here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html. I think broncoAbierto was thinking about your method name.

Comment: @AndreiNicusan thank you for the link,i will read that once after understanding the above doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
why nums[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1); , (i+1)*(j+1) is used with +1.
```

If it would not be used with `+1` all positions where either i is 0 or j is 0 would be 0. For example, i=2 and j=0: If `+1` would **not** be used there, the result would be 2*0 = 0. Instead, it becomes 3.

The complete reason for this is not something that we can answer here, but depends on how the 2-dimensional-array is used later on in the code. Since all the code does is to create a two-dimensional array and then print the values of it, the +1 is needed there to print out that result.

```
why first array[] is used to intialize the for-each loop i.e in line for(int x[]:nums)..
```

Because when iterating over a 2-dimensional array, each position will be a one-dimensional array. And then you have to iterate over the one-dimensional array to print out each single item (each `int`).

For example, consider a chessboard. When you iterate over the chessboard, you iterate over the columns/rows. Then, when you have a column/row, you have to iterate over it to get each square of the chessboard. When you have finished iterating over one column/row, the outer iteration proceeds to the next column/row.

Comment: What does it mean exactly by this line `nums[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1);` ? ,what i understanding is, this line is assigning values to 2D array.

Comment: @Danny Yes, it is simply assigning values to the array. It calculates the value for index `[i][j]` by using i and j in the calculation. So if `i` equals 2 and `j` equals 3, the value becomes `(2+1)*(3+1)` = `3 * 4` = 12.

Comment: @Danny You probably need to eat some waffles.

Answer (score 1):

> why nums[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1); , (i+1)*(j+1) is used with +1.

This is totally arbitrary and it's just for assign values to the 2 dimensional array.

> why first array[] is used to intialize the for-each loop i.e in line
>   for(int x[]:nums)..

Because it's a 2 dimensional array, so to access all the elements, you have to access each sub array first and then the elements in these subarrays.

Comment: Please wait, i am trying to understan your word meanings

Comment: Actually i understood now, its very basic question. I should not ask,its simply assigning some values , its not magic things going there. I am thinking so deep thats why i am not understanding

Answer (score 0):

**nums[i][j]=(i+1)*(j+1); , (i+1)*(j+1)**

It is used to assign the value to the array.

**why first array[] is used to intialize the for-each loop i.e in line for(int x[]:nums).**.

It is Enhanced for loop.So if you go back to the text book , this  for loop is added in JDK5 and is designed to cycle through a collection of objects, such as an array in strictly sequential fashion from start to finish.

**for(int x[]:nums){
}**

Here nums is a 2D array and with each iteration of the loop the next element is retrieved which is an array and stored in x that's why you need to declare x as one dimensional array. 
x is a temporary variable which refers to one element from nums in each iteration and elements of nums are 1 dimensional array so the *type* of  x must be declared as array.